# How to delete list entry with the help of a vector?

Tags: r, list

I want to delete some list entries. The entries to be deleted are stored in **delete_vector**.

Example with **flights**:

```
list_flights<-dlply(flights,"carrier", function(x)subset(x, select = c(dest,air_time,flight)))
delete_vector<-c("AA","EV","VX")#should be removed from my list
```

I want to use **delete_vector** for this and not like:

```
list_flights$AA <- NULL
```

Many thanks for your help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can use `[` instead of `$` for selecting multiple `list` elements.  According to `?Extract`

> The most important distinction between [, [[ and $ is that the [ can select more than one element whereas the other two select a single element.

```
list_flights[delete_vector] <- NULL
```

Answer (score 1):

We can subset the `names` of list and select the ones which are not present in `delete_vector` using `%in%`

```
new_flights <- list_flights[!names(list_flights) %in% delete_vector]
```

Or using `setdiff`

```
new_flights <- list_flights[setdiff(names(list_flights), delete_vector)]
```